Clicking at the bottom of the screen during full-screen gaming switches to to desktop
I was playing Minecraft in full-screen mode. When I click at the bottom of the screen, it automatically minimize the game and switches to the desktop.
This never happened in the past.

Not expected in a default desktop. You may have a gnome shell extension installed that triggers this behavior.
